# Sum specific properties values of objects in array if they have same property name and return unique array as result using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, reduce

my problem is to map two array of objects and sum their specifics properties if they have same name value.

For example if I would like to sum x and y of all objects where property name is 'v' etc.
Here is my code

```
var arr = [{name:'v', x:1, b:2, c:3},{name:'r', x:2, b:0, c:3},{name:'v', x:4, b:3, c:3}, {name:'v', x:1, b:1, c:3}];
let arr2 = []
let obj = {name:null, x:null, b: null, c:null}
arr.map(item => {
for(let i=0; i<= arr.length; i++){

    if(item.name === arr[i].name){
     let a = arr.reduce((a, b) => ({x: a.x + b.x, b: a.b + b.b})); 
      obj.name = item.name, obj.x = a.x, obj.b = a.b, obj.c = item.c
    } else {
    obj.name = item.name, obj.x=item.x, obj.b=item.b, obj.c=item.c
        }
  arr2.push(obj)
        }
  }
)

console.log(arr2)
```

As result i would like to return array like this

```
arr2 = [{name: 'v', x: 6, b: 6, c: 3}, {name: 'r', x:2, b:0, c:1}]
```

Comment: Note: property c does not need to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sumProperties = (arr) => {
  const result = [];
  const map = new Map();
  for (const obj of arr) {
    const key = obj.name;
    if (!map.has(key)) {
      map.set(key, obj);
    } else {
      const oldObj = map.get(key);
      const newObj = { ...oldObj, ...obj };
      map.set(key, newObj);
    }
  }
  map.forEach((value) => {
    result.push(value);
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(sumProperties(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for my question

```
var arr = [{v:'v', x:1, b:2, c:3},{v:'r', x:2, b:0, c:3},{v:'v', x:4, b:3, c:3},{v:'v', x:10, b:3, c:3},{v:'r', x:1, b:1, c:3},{v:'v', x:11, b:2, c:3},{v:'r', x:22, b:0, c:3}];
let arr2 = []
for(let j=0; j< arr.length;j++){
    for(let i=j+1; i< arr.length; i++){
        let obj = {v:null, x:null, b: null, c:null}
        if(arr[j].v === arr[i].v ){
          let a =  arr.filter(({v})=> v === arr[j].v).reduce((a, b) => ({x: a.x + b.x, b: a.b + b.b})); 
        obj.v = arr[j].v
        obj.x = a.x 
        obj.b = a.b 
        obj.c = arr[j].c  
        i= arr.length
        console.log("DA", obj)
        if(!arr2.some(item=> item.v === obj.v)){
            arr2.push(obj)
        }
    } else if(i+1 === arr.length){  
        obj.v = arr[j].v 
        obj.x = arr[j].x 
        obj.b = arr[j].b 
        obj.c = arr[j].c
        console.log("NE", obj)
        if(!arr2.some(item=> item.v === obj.v)){
            arr2.push(obj)
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(arr2, "REZ")
```

Comment: is this what you wanted :o

Comment: Yes sir, this solution resolve my problem.

Comment: ahh. was curious since it gave `[{ b: 6, c: 3, v: undefined, x: 8 }]` as answer

Comment: Ah, you was right. Check code now please, it should work.

Comment: good that you have tried solving instead of waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{name:'v', x:1, b:2, c:3},{name:'r', x:2, b:0, c:3},{name:'v', x:4, b:3, c:3}, {name:'v', x:1, b:1, c:3}];

arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
     if(!acc[curr.name])
     {
         acc[curr.name] = {name:curr.name, x:0, b:0, c:0};
     }
     acc[curr.name].x +=curr.x;
     acc[curr.name].b +=curr.b;
     acc[curr.name].c +=curr.c;

     return acc;

    },{})
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "v": {
        "name": "v",
        "x": 6,
        "b": 6,
        "c": 9
    },
    "r": {
        "name": "r",
        "x": 2,
        "b": 0,
        "c": 3
    } }
```